# Update the value of a variable every 5 mins

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a variable whose value needs to be updated every 5 mins depending on a condition. I am aware that I need to start a different thread. But how can I do that?

Comment: Google "ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor"

Comment: You really don't have to write `Java` in the title when it's tagged.

Comment: ... and see this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html

Comment: What research have you done?  What code have you tried?  SO isn't your research assistant.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), as shown below (based on [this code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0160__Thread/JDK15providesamechanismtocreateapoolascheduledtask.htm)):

```
public class Main{
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);    
   stpe.scheduleAtFixedRate(new YourJob(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
 }
}

class YourJob implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
   // your task
    System.out.println("Job 1");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/)

which is much easier..To schedule a task..

It's a good for `java` to run a program in a scheduled time

- Quartz Schedular features to postpone a task to run at a given time
- Loop execution also available

Answer (score 1):

**Thread way to do this,**

```
Thread t= new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {           
        public void run() 
        {
            while(true)
            {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
                    //change your variable values as required                       
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {

                }                                   
            }
        }
    });
```

**Thread pool executor way,**

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor myPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);    
        myPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyJob(), 0, 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES);       
    }
    class MyJob implements Runnable
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            //change your variable values as required in this function as this will be invoked every 5 minutes             
        }
    }
```

**Implementation by Timer**

```
Timer timer =new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() 
        {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                //change your variable values as required in this function as this will be invoked every 5 minutes   

            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, new Date(), 5 * 60 * 1000); //Use this if you want the new task to be invoked after completion of prior task only              
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, new Date(), 5 * 60 * 1000);//Use this if you want the new task to be invoked after fixed interval 
                                                                   //but will no depend or wait on completion of the prior task
```

Comment: With "the old way" you mean "the way that was always broken for several reasons and was never a good idea" I assume?

Comment: @Voo no the old way does not mean not a good idea to do the things,

Comment: That was a slightly more interesting way to say that your old way implementation has at least one showstopper bug of handling the interrupted exception wrongly and suffers from clock drift. And yes those two things mean it's not a good way to do things.

Comment: @Voo thanks for your comments, I removed the old way in answer to take your point in consideration

Answer (score 0):

How about using `java.util.Timer`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring, you can annotate your method with @Scheduled, for example:

```
// Invoke method every 300000 ms (5 minutes)
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=300000)
public void myMethod() {
    // Your code here
}
```

Or you can take a look at Spring's documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled